# App Shell not generated when wildcard route (not found page) is presented in app

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, app-shell, app-initializer

Yea, I'm struggling with the Angular app-shell as I have a wildcard in my app routes. My project is a standalone Angular project. How can we solve this?

`app.config.server.ts` file:

```
import { mergeApplicationConfig, ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideServerRendering } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { appConfig } from './app.config';
import { ROUTES } from '@angular/router';
import { AppShellComponent } from './app-shell/app-shell.component';

const serverConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideServerRendering(),
    {
      provide: ROUTES,
      multi: true,
      useValue: [
        {
          path: 'shell',
          component: AppShellComponent,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

export const config = mergeApplicationConfig(appConfig, serverConfig);
```

I also experienced that if I use the `APP_INITIALIZER` and try to redirect to an error page (based on our logic), App-shell navigates to that error page and embeds that page into our HTML instead of embedding the app-shell page itself! How this can be resolved?!

`app.config.ts` file:

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER, ApplicationConfig, isDevMode } from '@angular/core';
import {
  Router,
  provideRouter,
  withEnabledBlockingInitialNavigation,
} from '@angular/router';
import { appRoutes } from './app.routes';

function initAppFactoryConfig(router: Router) {
  return () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    // We resolve the promise whatsoever! Because we want the app to complete 
    // its initialization... BUT based on our logic (e.g., if the file we're 
    // trying to load at initialization, couldn't get loaded), we may like to 
    // redirect to one of our app's pages and then resolve... In this case 
    // app-shell embeds the error page into the HTML instead!
    router.navigate(['/error-loading']);
    resolve(true);
  });
}

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(appRoutes, withEnabledBlockingInitialNavigation()),
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initAppFactoryConfig,
      deps: [Router],
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I've just hit it myself. When trying to generate an App Shell it runs through all my APP_INITIALIZERs and fails